# How do I populate a DataListBox during runtime?

Tags: mysql, vb6

I have a DataGrid on my form which is ok and works.. I want to get rid of the DataGrid and use a DataList, How do I do it. The code that I am using to fill my DataGrid is below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testitem;User=root;Password=mysql;Option=3;
End Sub"

Private Sub Command1_Click()
rs.Open "select * from item where itemname = '" & Text9.Text & "'", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Set DataList1.RowSource = rs
DataList1.DataField = itemno
Set DataGrid3.DataSource = rs
End Sub
```

The datagrid gets populated just fine but the datalist is always empty

What am I missing here?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code snippet (not tested):

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
   rs.Open "select * from item where itemname = '" & Text9.Text & "'", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
   Set DataGrid3.DataSource = rs     
   '//Set DataList1.RowSource = rs
   '//DataList1.DataField = itemno

   With rs
     Do While Not rs.eof
       Me.ListBox1.AddItem rs!itemno
       .MoveNext
     Loop
     .Close
   End With
 End Sub
```

or

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
   rs.Open "select * from item where itemname = '" & Text9.Text & "'", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
   Set DataGrid3.DataSource = rs  
   Set DataList1.RowSource = rs  
   DataList1.ListField = "itemno"
 End Sub
```